# Karate Json Object - JsonPaths for nested array objects

Tags: karate

I am using the karate [java-api](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#java-api) to work with Json objects. I have the below json to be created:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "b": [
                {
                    "c": "hello"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to `json.set("$.a[0].b[0].c", "hello")`, I get the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.util.LinkedHashMap and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.intuit.karate.Json.createPath(Json.java:232)
    at com.intuit.karate.Json.createPath(Json.java:246)
    at com.intuit.karate.Json.setInternal(Json.java:199)
    at com.intuit.karate.Json.set(Json.java:148)
```

The json path syntax is correct as cross checked, any other point(s) which I might be missing?

Edit: I'm using v1.1.0 of karate-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Karate where so much array nesting is not supported. To replicate:

```
* def foo = {}
* set foo.a[0].b[0].c = 'hello'
* print foo
```

Since you were keen to contribute to Karate, maybe you can fix this :) Feel free to open an issue.

Here's the workaround:

```
* def foo = {}
* set foo.a[0].b = [{ c: 'hello' }]
* print foo
```

Comment: never mind I opened an issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1799

Comment: Thank you Peter :D 
The workaround which I am currently using is ```foo.a[0].b = []```